# Isabelle: Axiomatization and Quickcheck vs auto solve_direct

Tags: isabelle, quickcheck, axiom

Again a small example with unexpected results.

```
theory Scratch
imports Main
begin

datatype test = aa | bb | plus test test

axiomatization where
   testIdemo : "x == plus x x"

lemma test1 : "y == plus y y"
```

Now i get the following messages:

```
Auto solve_direct: The current goal can be solved directly with
  Scratch.testIdemo: ?x ≡ test.plus ?x ?x 
Auto Quickcheck found a counterexample:
  y = aa
Evaluated terms:
  test.plus y y = test.plus aa aa
```

and when i try to run sledgehammer i get:

```
"remote_vampire": Try this: using testIdemo by auto (0.0 ms). 
"spass": The prover derived "False" from "test.distinct(5)" and "testIdemo". 
This could be due to inconsistent axioms (including "sorry"s) or to a bug in Sledgehammer. 
If the problem persists, please contact the Isabelle developers.
```

Is this due to me messing with ==?
Or do i need to set some other sort of restriction for my axioms?

Follow up:

Apparently i should not play with equals :P
So i need to define my own relation.

```
axiomatization
testEQ ::  "test ⇒ test ⇒ bool" (infixl "=" 1)
  where
reflexive [intro]: "x = x" and
substitution [elim]: "x = y ⟹ B x = B y" and
symmetric : "x = y ⟹ y = x"
```

So i guess i have to define my basic properties. reflexiveness, substitution and symmetry seem nice for a start. I could make it generic with 'a => 'a => bool

now i would go on to define more of my relation. to stay with the example:

```
axiomatization
  plus :: "test⇒ test⇒ test" (infixl "+" 35)
where
  commutative:  "x + y         = y + x"  and
  idemo:  "x + x           = x"
```

a) Is this so far correct
b) How to proceed from here
So far i don't think this would replace subterms out of lemmas which is kinda the point of equivalence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your axiom implies e.g. `aa = plus aa aa`, which is false, because constructors of a datatype are *always* distinct, by construction. (cf. `thm test.distinct`)

In fact, if you use `axiomatization`, you should really know what you're doing – it's very easy to introduce inconsistencies that way. (obviously)

If you want to have a type with certain properties, you have to construct it. For instance, you could define a representation type of your type (e.g. as a datatype), then define some equality relation on it (i.e. what values should be equal to what other values) and then define the ‘real’ type as the quotient type of your representation type over that relation.

Comment: I see, could you point me towards an example of such a construct? or expand a bit on how to the equailty relation?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do exactly. You can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23478260/what-is-a-quotient-type-pattern-in-isabelle and http://www21.in.tum.de/~kuncar/huffman-kuncar-itp2012.pdf . If you can explain in more detail what you want to do in this question or a follow-up question, I shall gladly attempt to help you with it.

Comment: thanks for the offer. i've added my attempt at creating an equality relation. I'm currently reading http://www4.in.tum.de/~urbanc/Publications/sac-11.pdf, which is a bit more hands on than kuncar-huffman.